# Magento sales order grid customization

Tags: php, magento

I want to customize magento order grid. I need to add one more column which is in the table `sales_flat_order_address`. The link to the main table ie `sales_flat_order_grid` is `parent_id`.

Need to join such a way that `sales_flat_order_address.entity_id = sales_flat_order_grid.parent_id`.

But when I try for this i am getting an error "**Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in group statement is ambiguous**".

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()
joinLeft(array('table_alias2'=>$collection->getTable('deliveryinfo/saleslocation')),'main_table.entity_id = table_alias2.parent_id',array('table_alias2.entity_id'));
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find nice tutorial for adding columns to order grid:
http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/07/27/adding-order-attribute-to-orders-grid-in-magento-1-4-1.html

UPD:
Page is blocked now, here is a copy from archive.org

https://web.archive.org/web/20160120164619/http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/07/27/adding-order-attribute-to-orders-grid-in-magento-1-4-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste 
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php

http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
     * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
     * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
     * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
     *
     * DISCLAIMER
     *
     * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
     * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
     * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
     *
     * @category    Mage
     * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
     * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
     * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
     */

```
/**
 * Adminhtml sales orders grid
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('total_qty_ordered'));
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
        'main_table.entity_id = billing.parent_id AND billing.address_type="billing"',array('billing.postcode AS bp', 'billing.city AS bc', 'billing.email AS be', 'billing.telephone AS bt',));
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_payment', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id',array('method'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

       $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Id'), //Order #=order id
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'=> 'text',
        'index' => 'increment_id',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.increment_id',
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'filter_index' => 'main_table.store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'width'      => '30',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));

        /*$this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.billing_name',
        ));*/

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.shipping_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));

        /*$this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));*/

        $this->addColumn('total_qty_ordered', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
        'index' => 'total_qty_ordered',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order.total_qty_ordered',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('bp', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pincode'),
        'index' => 'bp',
        'width' => '60px',
        'filter_index'  => 'billing.postcode'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('bc', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('City'),
        'index' => 'bc',
        'width' => '60px',
        'filter_index'  => 'billing.city'
        ));
        /*$this->addColumn('be', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('E-mail'),
        'index' => 'be',
        'width' => '60px',
        'filter_index'  => 'billing.email'
        ));*/
        $this->addColumn('bt', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Mobile'),
        'index' => 'bt',
        'width' => '60px',
        'filter_index'  => 'billing.telephone'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('method', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Method'),
        'index' => 'method',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_payment.method',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id'
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```